# Create opportunity/sale from external website - options

Tags: apex, rest-api, login, user-registration

I'm creating a wordpress-webshop, where the user will go through some steps and then register a sale/opportunity in salesforce. The user will not have an account in salesforce before this point.

What are my options to retrieve a accesstoken, in order to create an opportunity in salesforce (through rest-api)? Is it only the sign-in auth-way? Because as I mentioned, the user will not have a salesforce account before the wordpress checkout-page. And allowing the user to create a user in the commununity at this point will create an awful lot of back and forth before finally being able to place the order.

Or another option for me would be to use the Apex public rest api to create a user with data from my form-fields? But would this be safe?

Comment: You can use email service to create records.

Comment: @tushar-sharma Thanks. Can I also use email services to create users in salesforce? Like, creating fields in my website for email, password and then it sends a mail, which in turn creates the salesforceuser and then creates the opportunity? :)

Comment: Yes you can create user as well.

Comment: @TusharSharma ok, thanks. 
I was also thinking, maybe a better option would be to create a public rest api wit apex, which will create a user and a opportunity. Do you know if this is alright aswell (provided I do proper validations before trying to create)?

Comment: Yes you can use that as well. No harm.